# 'No peer certificate' exception, but only on Mobile Data

Tags: java, android, ssl

How is it possible that I get 'javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate' exception, but only on Mobile Data. When WiFi is connected it works fine.

My Device ist running CM 11 M10.
The certificate is issued by StartCom.

Here is my Code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://" + hostName + ":8080");

HttpResponse httpResponse;
try
{
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); // this throw 'javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException'
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Perhaps there is some sort of transparent proxy at the mobile carrier that is interfering with your SSL validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

I have changed the Listening Port from 8080 to 443. And it works.
But I can't use Port 443, because IIS is usually listening on this Port.

So I have searched another Port.
I can change the Port to **25** or **587** (both SMTP) an then it works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible that I get `SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate' exception`, but only on Mobile Data.

There are usually two reasons for this.

First, the clock on the device is wrong, and the certificate fails to validate due to `notBefore` and `notAfter`. After you go online, the device can update its clock and the certificate validates.

Second, the carrier is intercepting requests via a caching proxy. See, for example, [Death Twitches: Nokia Caught Wiretappin​g Encrypted Traffic From Its Handsets](http://falkvinge.net/2013/01/11/death-twitches-nokia-caught-wiretapping-encrypted-traffic-from-its-handsets/).